# SystemInfo - Get computer System Model via CMD - Extra spaces bug

Tags: batch-file, space, extra, sysinfo

I'm trying to get a Computer System Model type via Batch file.
for this i've created this script:

```
systeminfo | find "System Model" > %temp%\TEMPSYSINFO.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (%temp%\TEMPSYSINFO.txt) do set SYSMODEL=%%a
del %temp%\TEMPSYSINFO.txt
set SYSMODEL=%SYSMODEL:~1%
echo %SYSMODEL% >%temp%\SYSMODEL.txt
del %temp%\SYSMODEL.txt
set "Line1=*** System Model: %SYSMODEL%"
echo %Line1%
```

but when I run it i get extra spaces:

```
*** System Model:              OptiPlex 9010
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it the hard way.  Use `wmic`.  It's a lot faster and less complicated to scrape.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic computersystem get model /format:list') do set "SYSMODEL=%%I"
set "Line1=*** System Model: %SYSMODEL%"
echo %Line1%
```

`wmic` lets you query all sorts of neat wmi garbage.  `wmic /?` for more info.

(updated per OP's comment under Fuzzy Button's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
for /F "tokens=2* delims=: " %%a in (%temp%\TEMPSYSINFO.txt) do set SYSMODEL=%%b
```

meaning use delimiters COLON or SPACE, making the text token3 BUT as the text might? include colon or space, the `*` means 'the rest of the line following the delimiters after token 2
`the first-mentioned token (2) is the one that gets assigned to`%%a`, the next highest (*) to`%%b`

Now you could also code

```
for /F "tokens=2* delims=: " %%a in (
 'systeminfo 2^>nul ^| find "System Model" '
 ) do set SYSMODEL=%%b
```

which means you don't need the TEMPSYSINFO.txt file. This executes the single-quoted command line - the special characters `>` and `|` need a caret (`^`) to 'escape' them (turn off their special meaning) as far as the FOR is concerned (they belong to the `quoted command`, not the FOR.)

The 2>nul will suppress the SYSTEMINFO progress text.

And it's quite legitimate to break this line - just have to be careful precisely where you do it. Makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I tried this and it replaced all double spaces to nothing,
with `echo =%SYSMODEL%=` producing :
`=my sysmodel =` (just one trailing space) :)

`set SYSMODEL=%SYSMODEL:  =%`

**EDIT**
So, using Peter's excellent suggestion to put the piped commands into the `FOR /F`, which I tried that before but came unstuck with a plain `|` instead of `^|` :)

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo 2^>nul ^| find "System Model"') do set SYSMODEL=%%a
set SYSMODEL=%SYSMODEL:  =%
```

**EDIT 2**
rojo's answer is great, but it still leaves trailing space for me, so I ended up still using the `%var:  =%` trick

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic computersystem get model /format:list') do set SYSMODEL=%%a
set SYSMODEL=%SYSMODEL:  =%
echo =%SYSMODEL%=
```

Comment: Thanks Fuzzy! I found that "wmic computersystem get model" is much faster, but now I need to figure out how do I put the model string with this command into set "Line1=*** System Model: %SYSMODEL%"

Comment: @EliranCohen - I updated my answer for you to address this request.