# Batch Scripting - Saving the output of systeminfo command to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having a hard time trying to save the output of the following command, which gets me the name of the OS to a variable.

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"
```

I tried using a for loop as shown below but then the value of the variable is `OS`

```
for /f %%i in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /B /C:"OS Name" ') do set vard=%%i
echo the operating system name 2 is %vard%
```

Can someone please help me out with this ? 
I took a look at other approaches such as writing the output to a temporary file and then reading it back later on but I'd like to achieve this without resorting to using temporary files

Comment: I suggest you to type `FOR /?` in cmd's command prompt and carefully read the help text. there is even an example of how to extract a specific token. The output from running `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"` will be something like this: `OS Name:    Microsoft Windows ....` there are multiple tokens delimited by spaces, you will need the rest of the tokens after the second token(`Name:`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SystemInfo - Get computer System Model via CMD - Extra spaces bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973276/systeminfo-get-computer-system-model-via-cmd-extra-spaces-bug)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "vard="

for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=: " %%i in ('systeminfo') do (
    if "%%~i %%~j" == "OS Name" (
        call :clean_spaces "%%~k"
        goto :next
    )
)

:next
echo the operating system name 2 is "%vard%"
exit /b

:clean_spaces
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=%~1"
    :loop
    if "!string:~-1!" == " " (
        set "string=!string:~,-1!"
        goto :loop
    )
endlocal & set "vard=%string%"
```

Delimit by colon and space. Unfortunately, token `*` also
gets the trailing spaces which `systeminfo` outputs.

A label named `:trim_spaces` trims the trailing spaces
from the value that `vard` stores. It does this by
checking the last character if a space and removes it.
It keeps looping until no trailing spaces exist.

Answer (score 0):

To use the slow `SystemInfo` method, as used in your posted code, you should delimit the output using the known separator character, `:`.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('SystemInfo^|Find /I "OS Name"'
) Do Call :Sub %%B
Echo the operating system name 2 is %vard%
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "vard=%*"
Exit /B
```

Alternatively, you can either use the built-in WMI command line, `WMIC.exe`.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=|" %%A In ('WMIC OS Get Name'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%A
Echo the operating system name 2 is %vard%
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "vard=%*"
Exit /B
```

Or retrieve the information from the registry, using `Reg.exe`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=2 Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V ProductName'
) Do Set "vard=%%B" 
Echo the operating system name 2 is %vard%
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```